# Несколько web-приложений от разных платформ на одном linux-сервере

Tags: django, сервер, java-ee

Есть стандартный Linux Ubuntu - сервер, на котором крутятся web-приложения Django. Необходимо на этом же сервере задеплоить web-приложение Java EE.

Как наилучшим образом это сделать - стоит ли использовать единую системную оболочку или лучше каждую среду запустить в контейнерном варианте?

P.S. Приветствуются любые ссылки в этом направлении!

Comment: Я всё деплою в контейнерах, запросы к ним проксирую через Front-end Nginx

Comment: То есть, каждое веб-приложение в отдельном контейнере или один контейнер для однотипных приложений? Какой способ Вам удобнее?

Comment: И что за контейнеры вы используете?

Comment: *Каждое* приложение я запускаю в отдельном Docker-контейнере